# How can I get the Textbox of a Tabpage in c# UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, tabs, textbox

I'm new at c# UWP and I have tried to make a tabcontrol, which worked fine.
Now I tried to get the current textbox of the tabcontrol, but it didn't worked.

I already did it in winforms which worked fine:

```
private RichTextBox GetRichTextBox()
    {
        RichTextBox richtext= null;
        TabPage tab = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

        if (tab != null)
        {
            richtext = tab .Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
        }
        return richtext ;
    }
```

So I have no idea how to do the same in UWP.

I would be happy if someone can help me :D

Edit:

The import of the NuGet

```
xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
```

Here the tabcontrol from MainPage.xaml:

```
<!--Tabcontrol-->
    <muxc:TabView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddTabButtonClick"
            TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested"
            Name="EditTabControl">
        <muxc:TabView.TabStripHeader>
            <Grid x:Name="ShellTitlebarInset" Background="Transparent" />
        </muxc:TabView.TabStripHeader>
        <muxc:TabView.TabStripFooter>
            <Grid x:Name="CustomDragRegion" Background="Transparent" />
        </muxc:TabView.TabStripFooter>
    </muxc:TabView>
```

And here how I've created the tabpages with the textbox

```
    void NewDocument(string text, string DocTitle)
    {
        var newTab = new muxc.TabViewItem();
        newTab.Header = DocTitle;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        Thickness margin = tb.Margin;
        margin.Top = 40;

        tb.Text = text;
        tb.Margin = margin;
        tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        tb.AcceptsReturn = true;
        tb.FontSize = 20;
        tb.IsSpellCheckEnabled = true;
        tb.IsHandwritingViewEnabled = true;
        tb.IsTapEnabled = true;
        ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(tb, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);
        ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(tb, ScrollBarVisibility.Auto);

        newTab.Content = tb;
        EditTabControl.TabItems.Add(newTab);
        EditTabControl.SelectedIndex = EditTabControl.TabItems.Count - 1;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please attach the UWP xaml code about the tab control and the textbox?

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to get the list of the TabViewItems first, after that you could get specific TabItem based on the index. And then you will be able to get the content of TabViewItem and it should be the TextBox Control.

You could refer to the following code:

```
          //get the tabitems array
        var TabItems = EditTabControl.TabItems.ToArray();
        //get the tabitem based on the index.
        MUXC.TabViewItem targetItem = (MUXC.TabViewItem)TabItems[0];
        //get the textbox you added to the tabitem
        TextBox content = (TextBox)targetItem.Content;
        //change the text
        content.Text = "This is test";
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer, it helped a lot. :D

Comment: @codingjuli If it solves your issue, you could accept it as answer so that it could help others who are facing the same issue.